# Android datePicker get day of week

Tags: java, android, datepicker

How to retrieve the next Saturday from current date datepicker this is my problem

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: how to retrieve the next Saturday from current date datepicker this is my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());

int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);//Try this
```

The variable `day` contains `1` for `SUNDAY`, `2` for `TUESDAY` and so on...

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());

while(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != 1) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
String nextSunday = calendar.getTime().toString();
```

you will find upcoming Sunday date..
nextSunday string format be like "Sun Mar 16 02:13:28 EET 2012"